# What is wrong with this use of the "fallthrough" keyword in Swift?

Tags: swift

In the following switch statement comparing tuples, I would expect it to print "point is on x axis" and "within test bounds", but instead it prints everything after the first matching case. Perhaps I misunderstood, but I thought that in Swift, fall through allows you to continue checking cases when you enter a case?

```
let switchPoint = (1,0)
switch switchPoint
{
    case (0,0):
        print("origin")
        fallthrough
    case (_,0):
        print("point is on x axis")
        fallthrough
    case (0,_):
        print("point is on y axis")
        fallthrough
    case (-2...2, -2...2):
        print("within test bounds")
        fallthrough
    default: print("outside test bounds")
}
```

Comment: Swift's `switch-case` is really meant for mutually exclusive cases. A series of `if` statements would better suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From apple's [documentation on fallthrough](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID443): "A fallthrough statement causes program execution to continue from one case in a switch statement to the next case. Program execution continues to the next case *even if the patterns of the case label do not match* the value of the switch statement’s control expression."

So Swift fallthrough is consistent with C behavior.

Comment: While it matches C's behavior, that seems very un-Swift-like -- especially since Swift has already eschewed the ++ operator and C-style for loops. You would expect fall through to simply let remaining cases to be matched.

Comment: So how do you continue matching case patterns? The Swift Programming Language document is misleading:

"If you need C-style fall through behavior, you can opt in to this behavior on a case-by-case basis with the fall through keyword."

Comment: That explanation seems accurate to me--using fallthrough gives C-style behavior, which doesn't continue matching cases. But yeah, like James mentioned, I would go with a series of if statements

Comment: "You would expect fall through to simply let remaining cases to be matched" - would you? I wouldn't. I think this behavior would be the one to seem odd and unexpected. `fallthrough` means "fall through the bottom of the case *and into the next one*", and it usually wouldn't go into the next one if it attempted to continue matching. But it might go into one way down the list, if it happened to match that. The behavior just wouldn't align with the words, and it would render most real-world usage of fall through behavior inoperative, since it would function so radically differently.

Comment: It is a bummer that `fallthrough` cannot be assigned to a label during `nested switch statements`. But I guess a labelled `break` could do the trick.